# Detecting sudden upward motion in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to detect an upward motion on my Android device but am finding this quite difficult. I've written the following code, and it works for all sudden motion (i.e. fast acceleration) on all directions. However, I would like this to work only for a sudden upward motion. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)
            // with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant
            // and dT, the event delivery rate

            final float alpha = 0.8f;

            gravity = new float[3];
            linear_acceleration = new float[3];
            linear_acceleration_old = new float[3];

            gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
            gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
            gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

            linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
            linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
            linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];

            System.out.println(linear_acceleration[0] + "  " 
                    + linear_acceleration[1]+"  " +linear_acceleration[2]);

            //detects swift movements, but I want to detect only upward ones
            if((Math.abs(linear_acceleration[1] - linear_acceleration_old[1]) > 10.0f 
                    && Math.abs(linear_acceleration[2] - linear_acceleration_old[2]) > 5.0f)
                    || isFirstEvent) {
                if(!isFirstEvent)
                    //do something

                linear_acceleration_old[0] = linear_acceleration[0];
                linear_acceleration_old[1] = linear_acceleration[1];
                linear_acceleration_old[2] = linear_acceleration[2];
                isFirstEvent= false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing, but since you initialize linear_acceleration_old at the top of the method it is full of zero values when you do if((Math.abs(linear_acceleration[1] - linear_acceleration_old[1]) > 10.0f etc. You could put the initialization in the class constructor instead. Some goes for gravity in fact. I don't know if that alone will make your code work though!

Comment: thanks james. you're partially right- im not entirely sure what I'm doning. my idea was to detect a difference in the old and current acceleration, and if this delta is sufficiently large, then trigger an event. however, im not entirely sure.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you meant by "upward", however:

1. letting the phone rest on the table surface and lift it up (make it higher than the table), would be a change in Z axis.
2. vertically holding the phone as if you are talking and then pull it up (raise it higher), would be a change in Y axis.

If you are interested in detecting these motions, you should modify your code to calculate deltas only in the relevant axis.

Comment: thanks. yeah thats what my code does. it calculates deltas only on linear_acceleration[1] (y axis) and linear_acceleration[2] (z axis).

Comment: I feel like you meant "&& isFirstEvent" instead of "||", so it only triggers once. I don't see the initial value of that boolean, but I assume you made it 'true' somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You should not operate only on x,y,z accelerometer sensors but take into account the orientation sensors too: [SensorManager.getOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29)

This way you can ensure the "upward" direction.